# Is there an algorithm for choosing which unknown points to input based on maximising a function of a row/column?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning

Is there an efficient algorithm for a small sparse table which will fill up with values based on selecting the unknown data points that has greatest POTENTIAL maximum scalar value taken as a function of a row/column for instance at the 95% confidence interval?

It would probably involve taking in each data point in the table currently and selecting the unknown data point which has the potential to maximise the result for the data. Once the result is entered the confidence interval will drop because #1) the sample size increases and #2) the result will most likely be somewhere around the other values and not the maximum. either way the same result cannot be entered.

Best explained with an example:
(the result to be maximised is average)

```
      | apples   | oranges  |
      | -------- | -------- |
alice | £4.50    | unknown  |

bob   | unknown  | £4.00    |

collin| unknown  | unknown

      | apples   | oranges  |
      | -------- | -------- |
alice | £4.50    | unknown  |

bob   | unknown  | £4.00    |

collin| £5.00    | unknown. |


      | apples   | oranges  |
      | -------- | -------- |
alice | £4.50    | unknown  |

bob   | unknown  | £4.00    |

collin| £5.00    | £6.00    |

      | apples   | oranges  |
      | -------- | -------- |
alice | £4.50    | unknown  |

bob   | £3.00    | £4.00    |

collin| £5.00    | £6.00    |

      | apples   | oranges  |
      | -------- | -------- |
alice | £4.50    | £9.00    |

bob   | £3.00    | £4.00    |

collin| £5.00    | £6.00    |
```

note that it also models the confidence interval of each row as well as column. the column names and row names are the same in my data but (x,y) != (y,x) as the relationship is different so x^y != y^x if that helps.

Thank you so much

pseudo code:

```
for column in columns:
   column_conf.append(conf_high(column))

for row in rows:   
   row_conf.append(conf_high(row))

for column_idx in range(columns):
    for row_idx in range(rows):
         x,y  = maximum(combine_conf(column_conf(column_idx, row_conf(row_idx)))
```

edit:
The set of x or y attributes are words but converted into vectors they are 60 dimensional and continuous between 0 and 1. Assume I've already got a method for determining which new word to choose based on a filled out grid of values. And now I want to trade-off the accuracy of the word generator for the the n^2-n complexity of adding a new word in order to arrive at an accurate solution quicker.

Comment: Please don't ask the question in your title, [edit] your post to have the title just be a quick to read summary of the problem, and then put the current title text in the actual post.

Comment: It's unclear. See [ask]. For example, what is the definition of "the result for the data"? I have to guess - at least it is a scalar because you said "maximize it". And what do you mean by "the result is entered"?

Comment: Might be related to the multi-armed bandit problem.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat You're right it is. if you could assist me in finding a solution based on my updated description I would greatly appreciate it. you're help is valuable and I want to acknowledge it properly.

Comment: After your edit, this sounds more like a(n approximate) nearest neighbor problem. There are a bunch of high-quality libraries for ANN in large numbers of dimensions.